# TypeError: command.execute is not a function

Tags: discord.js, typeerror

I am aware that this problem has been discussed already, but I don't seem to fit the solutions found into my code. I've created some commands to this bot and they seem to work, although they are only basic slash commands (e.g. /ping). This problem came in when I try to run a moderation command or a play command.

This is the code with the error

```js
const { Interaction } = require("discord.js");

module.exports = {
    name: 'interactionCreate',
    async execute(interaction, client) {
        if (!interaction.isCommand()) return;

        const command = client.commands.get(interaction.commandName);

        if (!command) return
        
        try{


            await command.execute(interaction, client);
        } catch (error) {
            console.log(error);
            await interaction.reply({
                content: 'A aparut o eroare cu aceasta comanda!', 
                ephemeral: true
            });
        } 

    },
    


};
```

None of the fixes that I found seem to fit, at least to my rather unexperienced eye.

The command I try to run is this:

```js
const { SlashCommandBuilder } = require("@discordjs/builders")
const { MessageEmbed } = require("discord.js")
const { QueryType } = require("discord-player")

module.exports = {
    data: new SlashCommandBuilder()
        .setName("play")
        .setDescription("Asculta muzica")
        .addSubcommand((subcommand)=>
            subcommand
                .setName("song")
                .setDescription("Incarca o singura melodie printr-un url")
                .addStringOption((option) => option.setName("url").setDescription("url-ul melodiei").setRequired(true)))
        .addSubcommand((subcommand) =>
            subcommand
                .setName("playlist")
                .setDescription("Incarca un playlist printr-un url")
                .addStringOption((option) => option.setName("url").setDescription("url-ul playlist-ului").setRequired(true)))
        .addSubcommand((subcommand) =>
            subcommand
                .setName("search")
                .setDescription("Cauta o melodie pe baza cuvintelor-cheie")
                .addStringOption((option) => 
                    option.setName("searchterms").setDescription("the search keywords").setRequired(true))),
        
        run: async ({ client, interaction }) => {
            if (interaction.member.voice.channel)
                return interaction.editReply("Trebuie sa fii pe un voice channel pentru a folosi aceasta comanda!")

            const queue = await client.player.createQueue(interaction.guild)
            if (!queue.connection) await queue.connect(interaction.member.voice.channel)

            let embed = new MessageEmbed()

            if (interaction.options.getSubcommand() === "song"){
                let url = interaction.options.getString("url")
                const result = await client.player.search(url, {
                    requestedBy: interaction.user,
                    searchEngine: QueryType.YOUTUBE_VIDEO
                })

                if (result.tracks.length === 0)
                    return interaction.editReply("Niciun rezultat")

                const song = result.tracks[0]
                await queue.addTrack(song)
                embed
                    .setDescription(`**[${song.title}](${song.url})**a fost adaugata`)
                    .setFooter({ text: `Durata: ${song.duration}`})

            } else if (interaction.options.getSubcommand() === "playlist"){
                let url = interaction.options.getString("url")
                const result = await client.player.search(url, {
                    requestedBy: interaction.user,
                    searchEngine: QueryType.YOUTUBE_PLAYLIST
                })

                if (result.tracks.length === 0)
                    return interaction.editReply("Niciun rezultat")

                const playlist = result.tracks
                await queue.addTrack(result.tracks)
                embed
                    .setDescription(`**${result.tracks.length} melodii din [${playlist.title}](${playlist.url})**a fost adaugata`)
                    .setFooter({ text: `Durata: ${playlist.duration}`})

            } else if (interaction.options.getSubcommand() === "search"){
                let url = interaction.options.getString("seatchterms")
                const result = await client.player.search(url, {
                    requestedBy: interaction.user,
                    searchEngine: QueryType.AUTO
                })

                if (result.tracks.length === 0)
                    return interaction.editReply("Niciun rezultat")

                const song = result.tracks[0]
                await queue.addTrack(song)
                embed
                    .setDescription(`**[${song.title}](${song.url})**a fost adaugata`)
                    .setFooter({ text: `Durata: ${song.duration}`})
            }
            if (!queue.playing) await queue.play()
            await interaction.editReply({
                embeds: [embed]
            })
                
        }
}
```

and the corresponding error:

```
TypeError: command.execute is not a function
    at Object.execute (C:\Users\shelby\Bot\src\events\interactionCreate.js:15:27)
    at Client.<anonymous> (C:\Users\shelby\Bot\src\functions\handelEvents.js:8:58)
    at Client.emit (node:events:513:28)
    at InteractionCreateAction.handle (C:\Users\shelby\Bot\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\actions\InteractionCreate.js:97:12)
    at module.exports [as INTERACTION_CREATE] (C:\Users\shelby\Bot\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\websocket\handlers\INTERACTION_CREATE.js:4:36)
    at WebSocketManager.handlePacket (C:\Users\shelby\Bot\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\websocket\WebSocketManager.js:352:31)
    at WebSocketShard.onPacket (C:\Users\shelby\Bot\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\websocket\WebSocketShard.js:489:22)
    at WebSocketShard.onMessage (C:\Users\shelby\Bot\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\websocket\WebSocketShard.js:328:10)
    at callListener (C:\Users\shelby\Bot\node_modules\ws\lib\event-target.js:290:14)
    at WebSocket.onMessage (C:\Users\shelby\Bot\node_modules\ws\lib\event-target.js:209:9)
```

Comment: Can you show the code for a command that is not working?

Comment: Can you add an example of a command as well as the complete error in your question?

Comment: In the command file, the function is named as `run()` but in the interactionCreate event handler, you are trying to run a function called `execute()` which doesn't exist. If you change `await command.execute()` to `await command.run()`, your code should work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be using `command.run()` instead of `command.execute()`, as your exported Slash Command uses this property name to store the core function.

```js
const { Interaction } = require("discord.js");

module.exports = {
    name: 'interactionCreate',
    async execute(interaction, client) {
        if (!interaction.isCommand()) return;

        const command = client.commands.get(interaction.commandName);

        if (!command) return
        
        try{


            await command.run({ interaction, client });
        } catch (error) {
            console.log(error);
            await interaction.reply({
                content: 'A aparut o eroare cu aceasta comanda!', 
                ephemeral: true
            });
        } 

    },
    


};
```

Additionally, you have to use an object that contains your interaction and client to run the function instead of using two arguments.